# How to use hosts.allow or hosts.deny in Android

Tags: firewall

Is there a way to use the files hosts.allow and hosts.deny in Android? I've searched over the internet but found nothing. 
I have to control access of both wifi and mobile networks. And limit the access to a certain domain. Just like a firewall do. I've tried to insert some iptables commands, but the system became very slow after these commands.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I know, Android isn't setup to use hosts.allow and hosts.deny

However, it *is* setup to use a standard hosts file in /system/etc/hosts

Unfortunately, it doesn't support wildcards, so it might be difficult to limit the device to a single domain via that method.

iptables probably are your best bet - perhaps you could post the rules you attempted, and I can see if there's anything that could be causing them to run too slow?